# Getting the sum in an arraylist

Tags: java

I'm creating a code to get all the sum of credit in the list. 
What I did below is:

```
List<CdTableValueEntity> accountCode = cdTableValueJpaRepository.findByKeyNameAndValue2("ACC_CODE_TYPE", "Revenue");
List<GeneralLedger> glClosingRecord = new ArrayList<>();    
for(GeneralLedger newRecord : glClosingRecord){
    newRecord.getCredit();
    BigDecimal totalCredit;
    totalCredit += newRecord.getCredit();
}
```

I get an error in this part `totalCredit += newRecord.getCredit();` The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal,

is the logic of my code correct?

Comment: a) declaring `totalCredit` inside the loop means it is not going to total anything. b) clearly you can't use `+=` on a `BigDecimal` in the way you are trying to...

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal.add()` method instead of `+=`

Answer (score 4):

> I get an error in this part `totalCredit += newRecord.getCredit();`

This is because `BigDecimal` is not a primitive data type. Therefore, none of the built-in operators, such as `+` or `*`, apply to it: you need to use [methods of `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Addition of `BigDecimal`s is expressed as follows:

```
totalCredit = totalCredit.add(newRecord.getCredit());
```

> is the logic of my code correct?

No, the logic is broken as well: you need to move `totalCredit` outside the loop, and initialize it to `BigDecimal.ZERO`.